# UIActivityIndicator not displayed

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a FirstView loaded with tableView and when a accessory button of tableviewCell is tapped then  it goes to SecondView.The data in SecondView is loaded from service url and so it takes time.So I need to show activityIndicator when accessorybutton is tapped, stop it after loading the whole data .BUt I couldnot see the activityindicator getting displayed.

This is the code Im working on :

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(143, 220, 37, 37)];
 activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
 activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
 activityIndicator.color = [UIColor redColor];
 [scrollView  addSubView:activityIndicator];
 [activityIndicator startAnimating];
 activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(140, 195, 37, 37);
 [activityIndicator startAnimating];

        SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
        secView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UILabel *name1 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:111];
        secView.provName = [name1 text];

        [self presentModalViewController: secView animated:NO];

        [secView release];
    }
```

Where I m going wrong?

EDIT:

SecondView:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
    activityIndictr = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(143, 220, 37, 37)];
    activityIndictr.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;

    activityIndictr.color = [UIColor redColor];
    [testscroll addSubview:activityIndictr];
    [activityIndictr startAnimating];

}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad]
   // I m calling many service urls(10) and assigning to labels and tableview 
  [activityIndictr stopAnimating];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call the activity indicator in the SecondView's `ViewWillAppear` , so that immediately after pushing in this view the activity indicator starts and then dismiss it when all the data is parsed from the url.

This is because the Second View Controller will be pushed almost immediately and the data will take time to load

Comment: gone with u but I dont see indicator getting displayed immediately after I tap accesssorybutton and appears after SecondView is completely loaded

Comment: @Sindhia how much time does it take for ur first view to go into the second view ?

Comment: I couldnot say exactly bcoz everything(data) is service oriented

Comment: Issue is I dont see indicator gtting added immediately when accessory is tapped but appears after secondView loads completely.I think i should go with queing or (threading) concept but donno how.Can u please tell me if I m wrong.

Comment: You should add the activity indicator before the did select in the first view and then it will continue to the second view where u can then dismiss it ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22943/discussion-between-sindhia-and-gill-the-ironman)

Comment: YES Im doing the same whatever it may be whether accessorybuttontapped or didSelectRow .But it is not displayed.I think so because immediately im writing  this :SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil]; so indicator is not displayed.Can I perform it with threading concept.?Any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You allocate *two* activity indicators, throw the first one away, then start animating the second one *twice* and never add any activity indicator into any existing view. No wonder it’s not showing up. Try `[[secView view] addSubview:activityIndicator]` or something similar.

Comment: Sorry but I dont get u.By this stmnt "throw the first one away" if first indicator is not used then y to create it.?

Answer (score 0):

Do this in viewWillAppear of SecondView :

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(143, 220, 37, 37)];
activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: Tried ur code but  I dont see indicator getting displayed immediately after I tap accesssorybutton and appears after SecondView is completely loaded.Anything elz should I need to modify?

Comment: Still the same result like the prevoius one.Dont now y

Comment: Yes in secondView viewwillAppear and did this [activityIndicator stopAnimating]; after [super viewDidLoad];

Comment: Is there any other code in viewWillAppear? For a time been remove [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

Comment: No no other code in viewwillappear.everything I have done in viewDidLoad

Comment: im on chat link.but its not responding

Comment: I can see your chat aren't you getting my reply?

Comment: this link also not responding

Comment: Ok can you copy paste your code in view will appear and view did load here from second view...

Comment: Checking.. Where are you adding these controls // I m calling many service urls(10) and assigning to labels and tableview??

Comment: See i can explain you the theory :
1. You need to add your controls. And then activity indicator. So that it can rotate till the time your controls get added.
2. You should not add activity indicatory and then add other controls coz they'll overlap it and you'll not be able to see it.

Comment: But Im calling each serviceurl,parsing the response and displaying a part of response to label ,similarly calling another serviceurl and doing the same procedure for all.I need to display activity indicator as soon as accesssorybutton is tapped and stop after the whole data is loaded in SecondView.How can I do it?

Comment: Rushi what elz can i modify?Do I need to work on the concept of threading?

Answer (score 0):

Again I have updated the answer.

put this code in appdelegate And define static object in appdelegate like below

static UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;

```
+(void)showActivityIndicator{

if (!activityView) {
    activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityView.center = CGPointMake(160, 230);
    [activityView startAnimating];
    UIWindow *win = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [win addSubview:activityView];
}
}


+(void)removeActivityIndicator{
if ([activityView superview]) {
    [activityView removeFromSuperview];
    activityView = nil;
}
}






- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

//global static activity indicator... you can access from any other view controlller

 [AppDelegate showActivityIndicator];

}
```

And after getting response

```
   [AppDelegate removeActivityIndicator];
```

Comment: I did it as u have said.Created activtyindicator in AppDelegate and calling it in accesssorybutton tapped.But it is not working.When I add a activityindicator to window in accessorybuttonTapped (FirstView)and remove it from SecondView after data is loaded then SecondView,Im getting error "activityIndicator undeclared.?How should I create it?

Comment: @Sindhia I have updated the code.. find it.. if you have any trouble let me know.

Comment: No it is not working Sachin.It is going to showActivityIndicator() but and executing the statements inside but immediatley as it comes back to  SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];indicator is not getting recognized.Can I make SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil] to start after 2 seconds activityindicator starts animating?

Comment: how do you remove activity indicator from second view?

Comment: [AppDelegate removeActivityIndicator]; like this as u have said from SecondView.I have this SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];in accessorybuttontapped event after [AppDelegate showActivityIndicator];